# Add symbol after and before of a character in R

Tags: vector, substring, character

I have a vector that looks like this:
    x=c("a,b,c,d")

[1] "a,b,c,d"

I want it to look like this:

```
"a","b","c","d"
```

So basically I am asking how to add "" symbol to each substring of the vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for `strsplit`, it splits the elements of a character vector x into substrings according to the matches to substring split within them.

`strsplit(x, "[,]")` is the answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the answer?  Helps the progeny.

Comment: 42 is the answer ;)

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted so others can easily tell that your problem has been resolved.